# unable to login thru ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-submit

I want to login to my system thru ajax but it is not happening, Please let me know hat's my fault. I'm new to ajax and CodeIgniter as well.

form:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <form  id="loginForm">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                      </div>        
                      <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="logins" class="btn btn-info">
                    </form>
```

Controller:

```
  public function login(){
     $data['subview'] = 'admin/parts/login';
     $data['title'] = 'LogIn To Account';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

        $this->load->view('admin/__layout_admin',$data);

    } else {

      // Get username
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      // Get and encrypt the password
      $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
      // Login user
      $user_id = $this->Users_model->login($username, $password);
        if($user_id){
        // Create session
        $user_data = array(
          'user_id' => $user_id,
          'username' => $username,
          'logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');
        redirect('users/login');
      } else {

        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
        redirect('users/login');
      }   
    }
  }
```

Model

```
   public function login($username, $password){

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $result = $this->db->get('users');
        if($result->num_rows() == 1){
            return $result->row(0)->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "login",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
            if (data== 'true')
            {   
               alert("success");
            }
            else{
               alert("Invalid Userid or password");
            }
         }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've tried every possible way and every tutorial saw almost but could not get the expected result, Please let me know my fault and tell me the correct procedure of ajax login

Comment: Why are you adding `"users/login"` to the base_url in your javascript code? check your console for errors

Comment: users/login is the controller

Comment: Yes but you are already passing it to `base_url()`... plus **Don't use MD5 for passwords hashing and use the built-in Password hashing API (password_* functions)**

Comment: sorry that is my mistake to write the user/login again. That has been removed now but still not working

Comment: By not working you mean what exactly? any errors? did you check the console? and again don't forget to **not use MD5**

Comment: you see md5 is at controller ,That's not an issue. I can't login currently.

Comment: Now It is partly working as I've removed `<?php echo base_url('users/login') ?>` and just put only  `'login'` but problem is it does not giving the `success` alert and I've to reload the page to see it is giving logout option at header

Comment: You need to debug the code, I've told you to check the console, post any errors you find **in the question**, I can't help you if you don't provide more details, and about MD5 not being an issue, **it is an issue**, a security issue.

Comment: in the console, there are no issues.It is clean  but problem is after clicking login it not showing logout button until unless i refresh the page

Comment: Don't use md5 http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php for passwords very insecure use this to create a hashed password http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php then to verify use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: I mean are you even reaching the correct page? Check your network tab in Dev tools.

Comment: Ajax will return a response and cannot redirect to another view page. Check @Alex 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following lines you specify that your `login` function in your controller will return a json encoded string. Yet you are doing three weird things: (1) not returning a json object (2) testing if data is true (part of (1)) (3) redirecting in your login function. Think of ajax like an hidden iframe, when you access something with it you have to make sure that the function returns (echos) something. In your case you can simply remove `dataType: 'json',` and in your login function *don't* redirect OR render a view. Echo true, or echo false. Redirecting is just redirecting in the "hidden iframe" and not in your "active" controller e.g. login.

```
        //dataType:'json',
        success: function (data) {
        if (data== 'true')
        {   
           window.location.href = '/users/login';
        }
        else{
           alert("Invalid Userid or password");
        }
```

Now depending on your `base_url` the above `window.location.href` may need to be modified. If its in your view you can even do `<?php echo site_url('/users/login'); ?>`.

Controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
    echo 'false';
    //$this->load->view('admin/__layout_admin',$data);

} else {

  // Get username
  $username = $this->input->post('username');
  // Get and encrypt the password
  $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
  // Login user
  $user_id = $this->Users_model->login($username, $password);
    if($user_id){
    // Create session
    $user_data = array(
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'username' => $username,
      'logged_in' => true
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
    // Set message
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');
    //redirect('users/login');
    echo 'true';
  } else {

    // Set message
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
    //redirect('users/login');
    echo 'false';
  }   
}
```

Now the limitations of this method is that as you are alerting on failed login and not reloading, any flash messages or form validation errors such as your `validation_errors()` won't be shown. If you do decide to redirect on failure then you have to consider that AJAX might not be suited for this particular application as in either case you'd be redirecting thus negating the whole reason of using ajax.

---

Now if you do want to get more fancy you can do something like:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error', 'msg'=>validation_errors());

} else {

  // Get username
  $username = $this->input->post('username');
  // Get and encrypt the password
  $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
  // Login user
  $user_id = $this->Users_model->login($username, $password);
    if($user_id){
    // Create session
    $user_data = array(
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'username' => $username,
      'logged_in' => true
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
    // Set message
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');
    //redirect('users/login');
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'msg'=>site_url('users/login'));
  } else {

    // Set message
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
    //redirect('users/login');
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error', 'msg'=> 'Login failed');
  }   
}
```

In ajax:

```
$("#loginForm").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "login",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
            if (data.status== 'success')
            {   
               window.location.href = data.msg;
            }
            else{
               // both validation errors and login failed
               alert(data.msg);
            }
         }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: And not to beat a dead horse but don't use md5: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure ... Use: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: all good but the code is always giving error like invalid unserid password though i have given correct  credential

Comment: That's another question entirely. But chances are you either didn't store the md5 password and stored the plaintext one or the credentials really don't match. I suggest you investigate along those lines.

Comment: So after removing the md5 now it works but the page is refreshing ,So what the use of Ajax ,I wanted to not load the page but login

Comment: Typically after users login you don't keep them at the same page... Add your own logic on this line `window.location.href = '/users/login'; }`